# Linux Disk Clean Up

Tags: linux, kernel, src

Is there any reason to keep the files in /usr/src ? I don't compile my kernel.

As most of my linux instances are on virtual machines keeping disk space to a minimum is important.

Thanks.

Comment: Alas, you are on the wrong Q&A site. [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would surely be a better choice...

Comment: Can I move it or just delete it?

Comment: If 2 other people vote for close, it will get moved to another site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say that if you're not planning to recompile that kernel, you could get rid off it and save some space.

Comment: That was my thought but I figured I'd ask. I much prefer to let others deal with the kernel....

Answer (score 1):

I always consider it very helpful not to delete wild, but to keep on your packet manager and remove the packets you don't need.

To be concrete, the kernel source is nearly always not needed, but can be very helpful for documentation.

Depending on which system you have: if you have a RPM based system,

```
rpm --queryformat='%{SIZE}\t%{NAME}\n' -qa |sort -n
```

can be helpful to identify the packets which occupy much space.